# Attaching key up event with multiple textbox jquery

Tags: jquery

i have two text boxes and i attached key up event with two text boxes but it is not working as expected. i want if user click enter if any text box has focus then i will check key press is enter or not. if enter key press then i will check two text boxes has value if yes then form will post other wise return false.

here is my code and just guide me what i am missing in code.

```
$(function () {
    var btns = $('#txtEmail,#txtPass');
    $.each(btns, function () {
        $(this).keyup(function (e) {
            if (e.type === 'keyup' && e.which === 13) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                alert(this.val());
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: each will run on document ready state , so everything inside will run at that moment, so the keyup event will be never recorded.

Comment: @BojanPetkovski to me it seems that he is correctly (though maybe not in the most straightforward way) binding the keyup event to the text fields (on document ready). Am I missing something?

Comment: @BojanPetkovski That is incorrect, this code is valid and [*does* work.](http://jsfiddle.net/n32ty26r/)

Comment: @Thomas, the code you have posted could be improved style wise but is valid and does what you want it to. Are you asking us to just write the rest of the logic for you? Have you tried anything yourself and if so how did it fail?

Comment: Now i see why is not executing the alert, because is referenced with this, and it should be alert($(this).val());

Comment: @BojanPetkovski good catch, I didn't spot that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution http://jsfiddle.net/y35zmqhg/

```
var btns = $('#txtEmail,#txtPass');
btns.on('keyup', function(e){
    if (e.which === 13) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert($(this).val());
        return false;
    }

});
```

Comment: That does exactly the same as OP's own code, only a bit more elegantly.

Comment: No need to check the type of the event I guess, as we've bound to the keyup event only.

Comment: Yes you are right, I am now riding the question as to figure out what he really wants :) Edited answer :)

Comment: I think you answered his question pretty much, his problem probably was accessing the current element from within the event with "this" ,ps he is using wrong syntax mexing js element and jquery function in `this.val()` and you solved it too

Comment: I believe he wants to check if the input fields have values on pressed enter or click on submit, and if they have to post the form

Comment: i made the mistake here in this line $(this).val() .... any way thanks for the help.